# XC8 : Cannot define auto array

Tags: c, xc8

I defined a auto char array as following :

```
char buffer[100];
```

When i compile it,the compiler return following error :

```
error: (1250) could not find space (100 bytes) for variable _buffer
```

But when i change it to:

```
static char buffer[100];
```

The program is compiled successfully.

Note 1:

My target device is 16f1829.

Note 2 :

Compiler version is 1.30.

Comment: An auto array in C is a stack local variable. The compiler for your microcontroller might know the available stack size. Check the configured stack size. Probably you can change it by compiler settings. Verify that the startup code you your project allocates that size for the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All PIC16's have RAM banks which are 80 bytes of usable RAM per bank. This is described in section 3.2.4 Common RAM in the datasheet.

The problem you are seeing is not related to the size of the stack but rather the size of each item which can be allocated on the stack.

On XC8 auto variables cannot individually be larger than one bank of ram, which means the largest auto variable possible will be 80 bytes.

This is described in detail in the XC8 Compilers Users Guide in section 5.5.2.2.3 as follows :

*Unlike with non-auto variables, it is not efficient to access auto variables within the compiled stack using the linear memory of enhanced mid-range devices. For all devices, including PIC18 and Enhanced mid-range PIC MCUs, each component of the compiled stack must fit entirely within one bank of data memory on the target device (however, you can have more than one component, each allocated to a different bank). This limits the size of objects within the stack to the maximum free space of the bank in which it is allocated. The more auto variables in the stack; the more restrictive the space is to large objects. Recall that SFRs on mid-range devices are usually present in each data bank, so the maximum amount of GPR available in each bank is typically less than the bank size for these devices.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes and it's not really a stack because xc8 functions are non-reentrant.
That means rather than use an actual stack to hold auto variables and parameters, it uses pre-allocated space in RAM.
Look at the call tree maps. You may have duplicated calls because if they can be called from both an interrupt and normal runtime they will be in different call trees and will therefore require separate allocations of memory (i.e. they will take up DOUBLE the space; potentially TRIPLE if you have three call tress)